# Replacing string in txt file with content of another txt file (regular expressions)

Tags: python, regex

I have two files: "invoiceencoded.txt"(base64 code) and "invoice.txt". I want to replace the word 'INPUT' in the second text file with the base64 code of the first text file. The purpose is to loop over the specific path for multiple examples of those, but that doesn't matter. I have the following code:

```
import re
import os
for f_name in os.listdir('C:/..'):
     if f_name.endswith('encoded.txt'):
         fin = open(f_name, "rt")
         filedata = fin.read()
         with open(f_name[:-11]+".txt", 'r+') as f:
                text = f.read()
                text = re.sub('INPUT', filedata, text)
                f.seek(0)
                f.write(text)
                f.truncate()
```

The 'INPUT' string is concatenated as 'abcINPUTdef'. However, instead of giving me

"abc*base64code*def", I get:

"abc*base64code*

def"

Does anyone know how to remove this line break?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably the line break is at the end of your base64 string in _invoiceencoded.txt_. Can you check if you get the desired result when you remove that?

Comment: You're right.. I feel stupid ;)
Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, sometimes one is too close to see. I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the line break is at the end of your base64 string in *invoiceencoded.txt*.

I'd suggest that you remove those line breaks and rerun your script.